# Writing generic mergeSort in C, can't assign value to void*

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, function-pointers, void-pointers

I am trying to code up a "generic" mergeSort in C:

```
void mergeSort(void *arr, int begin, int end,int size,
    int (*comp)(void *, void *));
```

But since you need a holder/temp array, it becomes a bit tricky.
I am not sure how to assign values to that array, since I created it as a void * array:

```
int mid = (begin + end) / 2;
int len = end - begin + 1;
void *pom = malloc(len*size);
```

But I can't assign values to that array, is there a way around it?

```
i = begin, j = mid + 1, k = 0;
while (i <= mid && j <= end)
    **pom[k++]** = ((*comp)((char*)arr + i*size, (char *)arr + j*size) <= 0) ? arr[i] : arr[j];
while (i <= mid)
    **pom[k++]** = arr[i++];
while (j <= end)
    **pom[k++]** = arr[j++];
```

the bold lines give off an error.

Comment: `**pom[k++]**` is certainly not correct C grammar.

Comment: You'll probably want to use `memcpy()`, which can copy to/from objects of arbitrary type.

Comment: Hint: start by sorting an array of string pointers. Step 2: change it to an array of void pointers. step 3) change them to void pointers, pointing to non-strings (eg: structs). Step 4) change it to an array of arbitrary objects, eg structs.

Comment: " I created it as a void * array" No you didn't, you created it as a byte array of `len*size` bytes. You could use this as an `uint8_t` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to copy `size` bytes.

So `**pom[k++]** = arr[i++];` becomes `memcpy(pom + size*(k++), arr+size*(i++), size);` and similar for all the others.